# jQuery simple tab content

Tags: jquery, html

```
<a onclick="changeTab(1)">Tab 1</a>
<a onclick="changeTab(2)">Tab 2</a>
<a onclick="changeTab(3)">Tab 3</a>

<div class="tab1" style="display: block";>Tab 1 Content</div>
<div class="tab2" style="display: none";>Tab 2 Content</div>
<div class="tab3" style="display: none";>Tab 3 Content</div>

function changeTab(tabNumber) {
   $( ".tab"+tabNumber ).slideToogle( 300 );
}
```

Hello together :)

I would like to realize a simple tab switching "widget".
I have 3 Buttons (Tab  1 - 3) and a content for each tab.

Content of Tab 1 will shown at the beginnen - the other 2 contents are hidden.
Now I would like to realize that I can click on Tab Button 2

=> this should hide the active tab content and shows the new tab content.

But my codes doesn't work at the moment like this - I know that - but I don't know how I can solve this issue :/

Comment: First of all I belive its `slideToggle` not `slideToogle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to hide the visible div.

```
function changeTab(tabNumber) {
  $('div[class^=tab]:visible').not(".tab" + tabNumber).slideToggle(300)
  $(".tab" + tabNumber).slideToggle(300);
}
```

If you don't it to hide when you click on the same, then use:

```
function changeTab(tabNumber) {
  $('div[class^=tab]:visible').hide();
  $(".tab" + tabNumber).slideToggle(300);
}
```

**demo**

```js
function changeTab(tabNumber) {
  $('div[class^=tab]:visible').not(".tab" + tabNumber).slideToggle(300)
  $(".tab" + tabNumber).slideToggle(300);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="changeTab(1)">Tab 1</a>
<a onclick="changeTab(2)">Tab 2</a>
<a onclick="changeTab(3)">Tab 3</a>

<div class="tab1" style="display: block" ;>Tab 1 Content</div>
<div class="tab2" style="display: none" ;>Tab 2 Content</div>
<div class="tab3" style="display: none" ;>Tab 3 Content</div>
```

Comment: Yes ! that's works ! BUT ^^ => If I click on tab 2 => tab 2 content will be shown. if I click tab 2 again, the tab 2 content will be hidden and no content will shown. Can we realize it, that this will not work like explained ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add common class to all tab div as `tab` and hide all tab div on call of `changeTab()` function and show relevant one.

NOTE: you have spelling mistake for `slideToggle`, you have put o instead of g. Please correct it

```js
function changeTab(tabNumber) {
  var $tabToSlide = $( ".tab"+tabNumber); 
  $( ".tab").not($tabToSlide).hide();
  $tabToSlide.slideToggle( 300 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="changeTab(1)">Tab 1</a>
<a onclick="changeTab(2)">Tab 2</a>
<a onclick="changeTab(3)">Tab 3</a>

<div class="tab tab1" style="display: block";>Tab 1 Content</div>
<div class="tab tab2" style="display: none";>Tab 2 Content</div>
<div class="tab tab3" style="display: none";>Tab 3 Content</div>
```